# Int stream and collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I am having trouble understanding the principle of this supplier ,accumulator  and combiner in the collect from `IntStream`. I found an example.

```
IntStream.range(6,11)
         .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                  StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                  StringBuilder::append);
```

Anyone mind explaining the `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's wrap this stream to make `byte[]` out of it and then `String` from the resulting array:

```
Arrays.toString(IntStream.range(6,11).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString().getBytes())
```

That would give us:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### How does the collect work?

It takes the stream of `6..10` and collects it in the following order:

1. It builds a new `StringBuilder` instance
2. It **accumulates**, that is appends Unicode code point using `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` to an accumulator. (equivalent to: `(StringBuilder sb, int x) -> sb.appendCodePoint(x)`)
3. It **combines**, that is adds the result of (2) to to the `StringBuilder` instance created in (1). (equivalent to: `(StringBuilder sb1, StringBuilder sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2)`)

The type signature of this parametrized `collect()` call looks like this:

```
collect(Supplier<StrinBuilder> supplier,
                  ObjIntConsumer<StrinBuilder> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<StrinBuilder, StrinBuilder> combiner);
```

Comment: Great example. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

What if we write it like this:

```
IntStream.range(6, 11)
          .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
             (StringBuilder sb, int x) -> sb.appendCodePoint(x),  
             StringBuilder::append);
```

The accumulator is a `Consumer`, that takes an `Integer` as argument and returns nothing.

`StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` is a method reference that does the same thing as the lambda expression.